# How to get the HTML as text using Anglesharp after the javascript has done loading the page?

Tags: javascript, c#, anglesharp

I am trying to use AngleSharp to crawl a webpage on my localhost. The page is generated using Angular js dynamically. I am using AngleSharp to get the page. Also using AngleSharp Scripting library to run Javascript. Below is my code for POC purpose. I am unable to figure out where can I find the HTML of the page after Javascript rendering is complete.

t.Result.Source.Text gives me the page source of the webpage. Where can I find the Source after javascript has finished rendering? I am even unable to figure out if the javascript ran or not !

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<IDocument> t = StartCrawl();
        t.Wait();
        string textContent = t.Result.Source.Text;
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static async Task<IDocument> StartCrawl()
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default
            .WithDefaultLoader()
            .WithCss()
            .WithJavaScript();

        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        var document = await context.OpenAsync("http://localhost:8000/#!/phones");
        return document;
    }
```

The view source of the url gives me this. How can I run all the javascripts on the page after page load. I can see 16 scripts in the document.Scripts property.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.animations.css" />

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app.config.js"></script>
    <script src="app.animations.js"></script>
    <script src="core/core.module.js"></script>
    <script src="core/checkmark/checkmark.filter.js"></script>
    <script src="core/phone/phone.module.js"></script>
    <script src="core/phone/phone.service.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-list/phone-list.module.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-list/phone-list.component.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-detail/phone-detail.module.js"></script>
    <script src="phone-detail/phone-detail.component.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="view-container">
      <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didnt find any good example. If you did find anything can you share with us ? Thank you.

Comment: @mbpakalin I didn't try it again. I hope there will be a way in C# to do it. I would suggest using puppeteer library (Node.js). It is easier to crawl JS rendered web-pages using it. It is a bit slow though but works perfectly.

Comment: i'm using cefSharp in c# right now. But it is kinda slow with it. Anglesharp is good but the documentation is so bad.

Comment: Sorry @mbpakalin if you find the documentation bad. What would you improve particularly?

I am quite sure that the JS did not execute. AngleSharp Js is still experimental and any advanced JS framework is out of the question. The debug console should show you the error (depending on the version you use, which unfortunately you did not specify, but assuming its something *very* old like 0.9 you will not see any output).

Regarding where to get the HTML - just serialize it. See my answer.

Comment: @FlorianRappl I'm going to learn angle sharp good and improve your document :)
You answered my question lately, i was looking thru the documents before opening the question but the documents is i think outdated. And btw, that worked perfectly thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AngleSharp (like in a browser) there is no notion of source *after* JS did something. You can look at the originally transferred source, but I guess that's not what you want.

If you want to see the string serialization of the DOM at a particular time (e.g., after some DOM manipulation by a JS script) then just do:

```
var currentSource = document.ToHtml(); // current serialization of the DOM
```

Note that this will represent your DOM in HTML (text) form.

What you did gives you the original source code:

```
var textContent = t.Result.Source.Text; // will always contain the original source
```